# I need help on a jQuery Cookie pop up

Tags: jquery, html, popup, onload

I need some help with a jQuery pop up, updating one of my clients websites and cannot get the code to work. Need it so that it appears on load, then when clicking I understand it will disappear for the remainder of the session.

See link to code pen - http://codepen.io/hazzaps/pen/bBjWwx

```
<div id="popup_disclaimer" style="height: 50%; width: 30%; position: fixed; background-color: white; left: 30%; right: 30%; top: 0%; border-radius: 5px; z-index: 100000; padding: 20px 50px 80px; box-shadow: rgb(84, 84, 84) 0px 0px 20px 3px;">
<h3 style=" TEXT-ALIGN: center; color: #b8292f;">DISCLAIMER</h3>
<p id="popup_disclaimer_text" style="
/* padding: 45px; */
max-height:;
max-height: 100%;
overflow: auto;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.    
</p>
<strong style="
float: right;
margin-top: 10px;
cursor: pointer;">
<a onclick="acceptTerms();">I Understand</a></strong>
  </div>
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**In jquery**:

```
$(window).load(function() {
//Display code here

});
```

Comment: That will show the code every time the window is refreshed, or a new page is loaded (given that the script is the same on all pages).

Comment: Tried adding that and did not work, did you see codepen link? also need it so that it only shows once on website when you first go on (whatever page you go on), then when clicking 'I understand' it will not appear again for the rest of the time you are on the site